# Registring models on django admin site

Tags: python, django

I have made a django admin superuser previously for a project  and now for another project i created another admin site super user but when i register models on admin site it gets registered  on both admin sites( i.e prev one and in new one)

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you sure you're talking about projects and not apps ?

Comment: actually for a new project i  registered a model for an app on admin site but i created a new super user for this new project so when i login to admin site with prev superuser id or i login with newsuperuser id  this model gets registerd in both of them...(i.e with prev  superuser id and newsuper user id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a Proxy model for you current model and register this Proxy model for your new admin panel.